# Java - BubbleSort Algorithm for list

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, bubble-sort

So i'm trying to use bubble sort to order my list but the output it gives after sorting comes out horrifically wrong. There seems to be some sort of problem in the code somewhere but i'm not too sure... might just be myself being stupid.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(45);
    list.add(6);
    list.add(234);
    list.add(8);
    list.add(9);

    bubbleSort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}
public static void bubbleSort(List<Integer> list) {

    int n = list.size();
    int temp = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-i; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (n - i - 1); j++) {

            if (list.get(j) > list.get(j+1)) {
                temp = list.get(j);
                list.set(j,list.get(j+1));
                list.set(list.get(j+1), temp);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The output it gives is `[1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 45]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your swapping

```
list.set(list.get(j+1), temp);
```

Should instead be

```
list.set(j+1, temp);
```

Using `list.get(j+1)` is setting a different index than you are intending

---

Also note that your list will not be fully sorted

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-i; i++)
```

That will only process about half of a reverse ordered array (5,4,3,2,1 -> 2,1,3,4,5)

Instead you should subtract 1 instead of i

```
for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
```